# How does one utilize a UIScrollView.?

Tags: iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have created a `UIScrollView` in my `VieController`. I have a bunch of UILabels that fill up the entire screen from the top to the bottom of the `UISrollView` (the `UIScrollView` extends below the ViewController). I am unsure how to utilize the `UIScrollView` and how I would code it to scroll down when the user does.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need to "code it to scroll down". it scrolls itself. set content size, add to view and that's it

Comment: I don't know how to set the content size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you see this excellent tutorial :

[How To Use UIScrollView to Scroll and Zoom Content in Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift)

You have to set the `contentSize` of the ScrollView or handle it's size by constraints inside of it.

Set the `contentSize` in the following way :

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 768, height: 2000)
```

Then you can scroll horizontally and vertically with the above example.

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for. Thanks.